# Modal dispersion in optical fibers

Tags: optics, dispersion, fiber-optics

I've got a couple of doubts regarding modal dispersion (with respect to optical fibers)

1. What's the difference between intermodal and intramodal dispersion?
2. How does intermodal dispersion affect bandwidth of multimode fibers?
3. How can intermodal and intramodal dispersion be reduced?

Comment: What's the motivation for this question?

Comment: I've got an exam coming up